# Optimising Spark read and write performance

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have around 12K binary files, each of 100mb in size and contains multiple compressed records with **variables** lengths. I am trying to find the most efficient way to read them, uncompress and then write back in parquet format. The cluster i have has is 6 nodes with 4 cores each.

At this moment with pseudocode below, it takes around 8 hrs to read all the files and writing back to parquet is very very slow.

```
def reader(file_name):
    keyMsgList = []
    with open(file_name, "rb") as f:
        while True:
            header = f.read(12)
            if not header:
                break
            keyBytes = header[0:8]
            msgLenBytes = header[8:12]

            # conver keyBytes & msgLenBytes to int 
            message = f.read(msgLen)
            keyMsgList.append((key, decode(message)))
    return keyMsgList
files = os.listdir("/path/to/binary/files")
rddFiles = sc.parallelize(files, 6000)
df = spark.createDataFrame(rddFiles.flatMap(reader), schema)
df.repartition(6000).write.mode("append").partitionBy("key").parquet("/directory")
```

The rational behind choosing 6000 here `sc.parallelize(files, 6000)` is creating partitions each with 200 MB in size i.e. `(12k files * 100mb size) / 200MB`. Being the sequential nature of file content that is needs to read each of them byte by byte, not sure if read can be further optimised?
Similarly, when writing back to parquet, the number in `repartition(6000)` is to make sure data is distributed uniformly and all executors can write in parallel. However, it turns out be a very slow operation.

One solution is to increase the number of executors, which will improve the read performance but not sure if it will improve writes?

Looking for any suggestion on how can I improve the performance here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Suggestion 1: do not use `repartition` but `coalesce`.

See [here](https://medium.com/@mrpowers/managing-spark-partitions-with-coalesce-and-repartition-4050c57ad5c4). You identified the bottleneck of the `repartition` operatio, this is because you have launched a full shuffle. With `coalesce` you won't do that. You will end up with *N* partitions also. They won't be as balanced as those you would get with `repartition` but does it matter ?

I would recommend you to favor `coalesce` rather than `repartition`

## Suggestion 2: 6000 partitions is maybe not optimal

Your application runs with 6 nodes with 4 cores. You have 6000 partitions. This means you have around 250 partitions by core (not even counting what is given to your master). That's, in my opinion, too much.

Since your partitions are small (around 200Mb) your master probably spend more time awaiting anwsers from executor than executing the queries.

I would recommend you to reduce the number of partitions

## Suggestion 3: can you use the DataFrame API ?

DataFrame API operations are generally faster and better than a hand-coded solution.

Maybe have a look at `pyspark.sql.functions` to see if you can find something there (see [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=save)). I don't know if it's relevent since I have not seen your data but that's a general recommendation I do from my experience.

Comment: i thought about no. of partitions i.e. 6k may be too high but out of concern that less partition may result in memory overflow they way files are being read. About df API, problem is `spark.read.format("binaryFile")` gets stuck without any indication about what is wrong.